# Alter or modify values of particular record in table using servlet jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I have created a JSP page which shows the existing values and the new values that need to be updated on submit. The servlet *Accountdetails.java* is used to process the data.

### Example

First Name: aaa
Enter the new first name in a text box to enter the new value.

Middle Name: bbb
Enter the new middle name and a textbox to enter the new value.

Last Name: ccc
Enter the new last name and a textbox to enter the new value.

Submit button to alter or modify a record.

1. Which is the best way to do it?
2. Which query should I used to update a particular record?

I'm stuck. because, I don't know which SQL query to use to update a particular record.
i.e removing existing value and update with the new one.

Comment: Google for "SQL tutorial".

Comment: An UPDATE Query would do

Comment: You should learn SQL and design patterns.

Comment: Where is the `edit.jsp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL update Query following as:

```
public void update(User user)
{
    try
    {
    PreparedStatement pr=connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE tablename SET firstname=?, middlename=?, lastname=? where acid=?");

          pr.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
          pr.setString(2, user.getMiddleName());
          pr.setString(3, user.getLastName());
          pr.setInt(4, user.getA.CNO());
          ps.executeUpdate();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          System.out.println(e);
     }
}
```

If you had any doubt for my answer pls give me comment.

Comment: jmail please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196385/unable-to-update-a-particular-record-in-table-using-servlet-and-jsp