# Unable to update a particular record in table using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

Hey guys I have created a jsp page for user where they can update their existing details and the record get updated in database on submit.

1.> **Accountdetails.java**

```
//Java Servlet program responsible for obtaining the user data and updating into   database    
package roseindia.net;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Accountdetails 
 */
 @WebServlet("/Accountdetails")
 public class Accountdetails extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Accountdetails() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Servlet is in the doGet method of account details");




}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Servlet is in the doPost method of account details");

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 
    pw.println("<html>");
    pw.println("<body>");
    pw.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Post</h1>");
    pw.println("</body>");
    pw.println("</html>");


    Connection conn=null;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName="userlogindb";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    try{  
      String Fname = request.getParameter("fname");  
      String Mname = request.getParameter("mname");  
      String Lname = request.getParameter("lname");  
      String Uname = request.getParameter("username");  
      String Emailid = request.getParameter("emailid");  
      String Mobno = request.getParameter("mobno");  
      String Address = request.getParameter("address");  
      String Password1 = request.getParameter("password1");  
      String Password2 = request.getParameter("password2");
      String ID = request.getParameter("id");

      Class.forName(driver);  
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,"root", "root");

          String update="update registerutable set fname='"+Fname+"', mname='"+Mname+"',    lname='"+Lname+"', username='"+Uname+"', emailid='"+Emailid+"', mobno='"+Mobno+"',    address='"+Address+"', password1='"+Password1+"', password2='"+Password2+"' where    id='"+ID+"' ";   

                System.out.println("The sql is " +update);
                     PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(update);


      pst.setString(1,Fname);  
      pst.setString(2,Mname);        
      pst.setString(3,Lname);
      pst.setString(4,Uname);
      pst.setString(5,Emailid);
      pst.setString(6,Mobno);
      pst.setString(7,Address);
      pst.setString(8,Password1);
      pst.setString(9,Password2);
      pst.setString(11,ID);


      int i = pst.executeUpdate();

      String msg=" ";
      if(i!=0){  
        msg="User Updated";

        pw.print(i);
        pw.print("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");  
        pw.print(" '"+Fname+"'");

      }  
      else{  
        msg="failed to update the data";
        pw.print("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");
       }  
      pw.close();
      pst.close();
      conn.close();
    }  
    catch (Exception e){  
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }  

}

 }
```

2.> **successful.jsp**

```
//JSP page which shows existing value and new value to be entered by user.

<form name="myaccountform" action="Accountdetails" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>First name:</td>
<%Object value11 = request.getAttribute("fname");%>
<td><%=value11%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter the new first name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Middle name:</td>
<%Object value12 = request.getAttribute("mname");%>
<td><%=value12%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter the new middle name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mname" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last name:</td>
<%Object value13 = request.getAttribute("lname");%>
<td><%=value13%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter the new last name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<%Object value14 = request.getAttribute("uname");%>
<td><%=value14%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter new username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email id:</td>
<%Object value15 = request.getAttribute("emailid");%>
<td><%=value15%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter new email id:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="emailid" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile number:</td>
<%Object value16 = request.getAttribute("mobno");%>
<td><%=value16%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter new mobile number:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobno" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<%Object value17 = request.getAttribute("address");%>
<td><%=value17%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter new address:</td>
<td><textarea rows="5" cols="15" name="address"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Old password:</td>
<%Object value18 = request.getAttribute("password1");%>
<td><%=value18%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter the new password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password1" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reenter the new password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password2" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

3.> **web.xml**

```
//mapping between servlet and jsp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>LoginExample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<description>Login Servlet</description>
<display-name>Login</display-name>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>roseindia.net.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<description>Servlet Example</description>
<display-name>ServletExample</display-name>
<servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servletexample.com.ServletExample</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<description>Account Details</description>
<display-name>Accountdetails</display-name>
<servlet-name>Accountdetails</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>roseindia.net.Accountdetails</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Accountdetails</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Accountdetails</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The problem here is when fill up all the fields and click on submit it is unable to update it.

It goes into else part showing failed to update the data.

When I sys out it shows The sql is

```
update registerutable set 
  fname='admin11', mname='admin11', lname='admin11', username='admin11',
  emailid='admin', mobno='1111', address='admin', password1='admin',  
  password2='admin' 
where id='null'
```

I also tried

```
String ID = request.getParameter("id");
```

to

```
int ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

but still unable to update it.

Please help me to correct as I dont know where m I going wrong now.

Comment: What is the datatype of ID in mysql database

Comment: JqueryLearner datatype is integer

Comment: When your are getting String ID = request.getParameter("id"); where is the element named id on jsp.

Comment: hey look at my update answer,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

---

Your servlet does not seem to be receiving the query parameter `id`.

```
String ID = request.getParameter("id");
```

This statement must be causing variabl `ID` to hold a `null`.

In your `JSP` you are not setting a form variable for `id` and hence it is not being received by `AccountDetails` servlet.

And hence the same `null` is passed to `update` query statement which is not updating any record in the database table.

```
update registerutable set 
  fname='admin11', mname='admin11', lname='admin11', username='admin11',
  emailid='admin', mobno='1111', address='admin', password1='admin',  
  password2='admin'
where id='null'
```

The condition `where id='null'` is not matching any records and hence not succeeded.

---

Your sql string for prepared statement is wrongly formed. You should have place holders for `PreparedStatement` to bind values with them.

Change:

```
String update=
  "update registerutable set 
   fname='"+Fname+"', mname='"+Mname+"', lname='"+Lname+"', 
   username='"+Uname+"', emailid='"+Emailid+"', mobno='"+Mobno+"',
   address='"+Address+"', password1='"+Password1+"', 
   password2='"+Password2+"' where id='"+ID+"' ";
```

To:

```
String update=
  "update registerutable set 
     fname=?, mname=?, lname=?, username=?, emailid=?, 
     mobno=?, address=?, password1=?, password2=? 
   where id=?";
```

Comment: Ravinder so how it can be corrected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add a hidden input field with name `'id'` and its value in your jsp. This value should be coming to it from its previous page.

Comment: Ravinder now it is showing The sql is update registerutable set fname='admin11', mname='admin11', lname='admin11', username='admin11', emailid='admin', mobno='1111', address='admin', password1='admin', password2='admin' where id='16' but still there is a one java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: For the last parameter `id`, it should be `10` but not `11`, in your code. Change `pst.setString(11,ID);` to `pst.setString(10,ID);`

Comment: Sorry Ravinder I dont need 10th field to be updated so I purposely left it

Comment: Ravinder I used your provided query for update but it now shows The sql is update registerutable set fname=?, mname=?, lname=?, username=?, emailid=?, mobno=?, address=?, password1=?, password2=? where id=?

Comment: No, we are not updating `10th` column in the table. We are just setting value for a parameter at index `10` in the `update` query. It is on `id` in `where` clause.

Comment: Ravinder I just change pst.setString(11, ID); to pst.setString(10, ID); but still it shows error java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). Can you please procced to stackoverflow chat room because stackoverflow is not allowing or please can we chat in gmail my gmail id : skatiq2786@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49060/discussion-between-atiq-and-ravinder)

Answer (score 2):

your code:

```
      pst.setString(9,Password2);
      pst.setString(11,ID);
```

you doing some mistake:

```
  pst.setString(9,Password2);
  pst.setString(10,ID);
```

you should look at this following line:

this field name, like as:(fault page)

```
      pst.setString(1,Fname);  
      pst.setString(2,Mname);        
      pst.setString(3,Lname);
      pst.setString(4,Uname);
      pst.setString(5,Emailid);
      pst.setString(6,Mobno);
      pst.setString(7,Address);
      pst.setString(8,Password1);
      pst.setString(9,Password2);
      pst.setString(11,ID);
```

now did you understand your error, you should change this and  compile it.

```
String update=
  "update registerutable set 
     fname=?, mname=?, lname=?, username=?, emailid=?, 
     mobno=?, address=?, password1=?, password2=? 
   where id=?";
```

Comment: @Atiq, you should must change that integer like (11 to change 10)

Comment: jmail sorry I dont need 10 field to be updated so I purposely left it

Comment: then how many field your using... look at your code your using 10field. but your give 11th field for ID. that only your getting the error...

Comment: jmail my 10th field is usertype which is not needed to be updated because of requirement

Comment: @Atiq, you didn't understand  look at your update part... first you should change it and run...definitely it will be clear

Comment: Yaa I got it ymail Sorry I was my lack of understanding

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49059/discussion-between-atiq-and-jmail)

Answer (score 0):

As the datatype is `int` in mysql datatbase for the **column ID**

so change       `pst.setString(11,ID);`
to       `pst.setInt(11,ID);`

But ID is a String so you need to convert it into `int` using `Integer.parseInt();`

Comment: JqueryLearner nope it is not working when replaced it to pst.setInt(11,ID);

Comment: @Atiq yes it will not work because there is no where name="ID" in the form,checked just now

Comment: Sorry JqueryLearner I dont need 10th field to be updated so I purposely left it

Answer (score 0):

you could try to modify the assignment to the string with reference update by replacing the variable names with question marks since you are using a prepared statement to perform the table update.